# The IVP for the PDE $u_t + (1+x^2)u_x=0$ is not well defined

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Show that the initial value problem for the equation 
$$u_t + (1+x^2)u_x=0$$

is not well defined

**My attempt:**

The characteristic ODE are

$\dfrac{d x}{ d t} = 1+x^2$,  $\dfrac{d u}{ d t} = 0$, with initial conditions $x(0)=x_0$,

The solutions of the ODE are

$\arctan (x) = t+\arctan (x_0) \Rightarrow x = \tan(t+\arctan (x_0)) $

Thus, the characteristic curves are the translates of the graph of the function arctan x.

I couldn't see why the IVP is not well defined.

Any help?

Comment: Can you find, for each $(x,t)$, a unique $x_0$ such that $\arctan(x)=t+\arctan(x_0)$? What if $x=0$ and $t=5000$?

Comment: Following up on my comment, the full solution to the method of characteristics proceeds like this: solve the characteristic equation, obtaining a function $c(t,x_0)$. Solve the ODE along the characteristics, obtaining a function $v(t,x_0)$. Then $u(t,c(t,x_0))=v(t,x_0)$. To finish writing the solution, you must solve the equation $x=c(t,x_0)$ for $x_0$ for each value of $t$; let's say this inverse is denoted by $y(t,x)$. Then the solution to the problem finally reads $u(t,x)=v(t,y(t,x))$. The problem here is that you cannot construct the function $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_t + (1+x^2)u_x=0$$
The system of characteristic differential equations is :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first equation of characteristic curve comes from : $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$
$$t-\tan^{-1}(x)=c_1$$
For $\frac{du}{0}$ to be finite, necessarily $du=0$  which leads to a second equation of characteristic curve :
$$u=c_2$$
Thus, the general solution of the PDE expressed as an implicit equation is :
$$\Phi\left(t-\tan^{-1}(x)\;,\;u\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

Solving for the second variable gives the explicit form of general solution :
$$u(x,t)=F\left(t-\tan^{-1}(x)\right)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function.

Now, with condition : $x(0)=x_0$
$$u(x_0,0)=F\left(0-\tan^{-1}(x_0)\right)$$
Since $F$ is any function, $u(x_0,0)$ is any constant. So, the initial condition of $u(x,y)$ is undetermined. As a consequence, the function $F$ cannot be determined in order to obtain a unique solution $u(x,y)$.

In other words, the condition $x(0)=x_0$ is not sufficient for the PDE to have a unique solution.

NOTE :

The equation of characteristic curves : 
$$t-\tan^{-1}(x)=c_1$$
together with the condition $x(0)=x_0$ implies $c_1=-\tan^{-1}(x_0)+n\pi$
$$t-\tan^{-1}(x)=-\tan^{-1}(x_0)+n\pi$$
Thus, for a given value $x_0$, there is not only one value of $t$.

Solving for $x$ leads to
$$x=\tan\left(t+\tan^{-1}(x_0)\right)$$
where $t$ isn't unique.

This is the equation of a set of characteristic curves. It must not be confused with the solutions of the PDE.

Comment: @263970 : Someone down-voted the above answer without asking for more explanation. It doesn't matter. But if you down-voted without fully to understand, I would like to give you an hint : In the wording of your question, you wrote : ''The solutions of the ODE are $x=\tan(t+\arctan(x_0))\;$". This is not the solution of the PDE because the unknown is $u(x,t)$ and you didn't wrote the general solution, nor the particular solution $u(x,t)$ with condition $x(0)=x_0$. Writing explicitly $u(x,t)$ is the key to fully understand.

Comment: I didn't down-vote your anwser.  Thank you for  your helpful  explanation!

Comment: I also didn't downvote the answer, but I will say that I find invoking the symbol "du/0" to be a very confusing way to think about the simple idea "$u$ is constant along the characteristics because $\frac{du}{dt}=0$ by the chain rule". Also, in this problem the issue is *not* non-uniqueness, but rather non-existence. It is not that multiple characteristics reach a given point $(t,x)$, it is that *no* characteristics reach $(t,x)$ if $t$ is too big compared to $x$. Writing $\tan^{-1}$ instead of $\arctan$ obfuscates this fact.